# Flat files CMS or static website generator to show directory structure and contents

Tags: file-management, web-development, cms, gallery

For a small NGO website, featuring lots of photo galleries and PDF documents, I am looking for CMS suggestions for a really simple flat file PHP CMS that, out of the box, will read a directory structure and show it, including multiple-folder hierarchy, static pages (TXT or HTML), image galleries (for folders with images) and document downloads (for folders with documents). If possible, uploading and folder creation would be an advantage.

I've been trying Kirby, Grav and other similar CMSes, but I still haven't found a solution without heavily customizing the systems... Is there a CMS that will do this without customization?

My idea is something like a "light" version of [Plone](https://plone.org/).

Comment: Have you considered a static web site generator rather than a full CMS?

Comment: That would work as well, as long as the solution has the features I'm looking for (image galleries, PDF document management, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at static web site generators such as [Hyde](http://hyde.github.io/) *([Python](https://www.python.org/))* or [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) *([Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/))* - Both are Free *gratis & open source* and cross platform *although Jekyll is not officially supported on Windows*.  There is a nice, if slightly dated, comparison of the two [here](http://philipm.at/2011/jekyll_vs_hyde.html).

In both cases you use templates and markdown, *just like here*, to define your site content and can include uploads of your documents, etc.